# No of ways to arrange colour pencils

Tags: combinatorics

$x$ red color,$y$ blue color and $z$ green color pencils are arranged in a row. How many ways can they be arranged so that no two green color pencils are together?

I thought of counting the total number of ways in which they can be arranged which is $(x+y+z)!$. Now I need to count the number of ways in which any two of them are together,but this lands me to the same question as the above.

Comment: As it is, this question will without a doubt get closed. You should include your thoughts. Questions that sound like "please do my homework" are not very well-received.

Comment: See if you can adapt the approach in this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264407/ways-to-place-3-red-4-blue-and-5-green-wagons-such-that-no-2-blue-wagons-were-s?rq=1).

Comment: Are we considering two red pencils as distinct objects? In that case, the total number of arrangements is less than $(x+ y + z) !$, since that is the number of of permutations of $x + y + z$ distinct objects.

Comment: I would calculate the number of arrangements that have at least 2 green pencils next to each other. The remaining ones are those that have no two green pencils next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Counting the total number of ways using $(x+y+z)!$ unfortunately doesn't work, as we consider e.g. each red pencil indistinguishable from the others, so you would get many repetitions. A better way is to use binomial coefficients - Consider the $n=x+y+z$ places where you must place pencils. First, place the green ones (this can be done in ${n}\choose{z}$ ways), then the blue, ${n-z}\choose{y}$, and finally the red - but there are only $x$ places to place those, so only one way to do it. Therefore the total number of arrangements are ${n}\choose{z}$${n-z}\choose{y}$.
Now, you could probably calculate the number of arrangements with two green pencils next to each other, but unfortunately that is not so simple. A better way to solve the problem may be the following:

Consider the ways you can arrange just the red and the blue pencils - this is ${x+y}\choose{x}$. Now, between each of the red and blue pencils we make a gap where we could possibly place a single green pencil. There are $x+y+1$ such spaces, as we could also place a green pencil at the ends. Then you can place the green pencils in exactly ${x+y+1}\choose{z}$ ways, and these are exactly the arrangements for which no two green pencils lie next to each other. Thus, the answer is ${x+y}\choose{x}$${x+y+1}\choose{z}$.